# me sale un error en mi codigo poo en php

Tags: php

estoy comenzando en php pero me atasque con este error y no tengo idea de que hacer estaba programando poo y la verdad no se que hice y estoy un poco desesperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
aquí dejo el código:
```

```php
<?php include("includes/header.php")?>
<?php include("includes/footer.php")?>

<?php 
class Automovil{

    public $marca;
    public $modelo;
    
          public function mostrar(){
    
        print "<p> hola tengo un $this->marca,model $this-> modelo </p>";
             }
    }
    $a = new Automovil();
    $a -> marca = "ferrari";
    $a -> modelo = "fxxk";
    $a -> mostrar();
    
    $b = new Automovil();
    $b -> marca ="lamborgini";
    $b -> modelo ="egoista";
    $b -> mostrar();
?>
```

Comment: La próxima vez copia y pega el texto del error y no pongas una gran captura de pantalla, y sé más descriptivo en el título, Consulta cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
print "<p> hola tengo un $this->marca,model $this-> modelo </p>";
```

En intérprete de PHP entiende la variable $this dentro de la cadena, pero no las propiedades, y menos aún si te dejas un espacio. Entonces, para usar $this (el objeto) en la cadena, intenta convertirlo a string, pero no puede y te da el error.

Tienes que, o bien concatenar, o bien usar llaves, o usar printf().

**Concatenando:**

```
print "<p>hola tengo un " . $this->marca . ", model " . $this->modelo . "</p>";
```

**Usando llaves:**

```
print "<p>hola tengo un {$this->marca}, model {$this->modelo}</p>";
```

**Usando printf():**

```
printf("<p>hola tengo un %s, model %s</p>", $this->marca, $this->modelo);
```

Answer (score 0):

La línea 12, en el print existe un error, ya que no has concatenado las propiedades del objeto automóvil. Adjunto el código con alguna modificación que me parece más elegante, como añadir el [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) de la clase, los [getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320334/get-set-properties-in-php) (método para obtener el valor de la propiedad de la clase) y los [setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320334/get-set-properties-in-php) (método para modificar las propiedades de la clase). Date cuenta que con el método get podrías hacer la impresión sin necesidad del método mostrar.

```
class Automovil{

    private $marca;
    private $modelo;
    
    public function __construct($marca, $modelo) {
        $this->marca = $marca;
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }

    public function getMarca(){
        return $this->marca;
    }
    
    public function getModelo(){
        return $this->modelo;
    }
    
    public function setMarca($marca){
        $this->marca = $marca;
    }
    
    public function setModelo($modelo){
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }
    
    public function mostrar(){
        echo "hola tengo un " . $this->marca . " modelo " . $this-> modelo ";
    }
}
$a = new Automovil("ferrari","fxxk");
$a->mostrar();
    
$b = new Automovil("lamborgini", "egoista");
$b->mostrar();

//Imprimir con el método get.
echo "Tengo un " . $a->getMarca() . " modelo " . $a->getModelo() . "
;
```